# Apple Script get result value from block of code

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a block of code that returns the current value of input language

```
tell process "SystemUIServer" to 
   get the value of the first menu bar item of menu bar 1 
   whose description is "text input"
tell end
```

Now I want to check the result with `IF Else` but I don't know how I should do it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to tell `System Events` to do the job.

Just assign the result to a variable

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        set textInput to (get value of the first menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description is "text input")
    end tell
end tell
```